# How to hide navbar when iframe is in full screen mode?

Tags: css, iframe, nav

I have a navbar set to a fixed position at the top of the screen with a z-index of 1. When I click my iframe to be in full screen mode the navbar still sits on top of the iframe. How do I hide my navbar or move my iframe to the front when I put it in full screen mode?

Comment: can you please provide the code so we can see what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways, either:

1) Hide the navbar

```
#navbar{
   display: none;
}
```

or...

2) Put the iframe above the navbar using the z-index property

```
iframe{
   z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is an example of the second method being applied using jQuery by adding a `.fullscreen` class: https://jsfiddle.net/gyq7tv9h/